# How much reputation do you get if your answer gets checkmarked?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

What other nifty rules are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When the original poster *accepts* your answer, the answer gets a green checkmark and you get 15 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Other nifty rules can be found on Meta Stack Overflow [tagged as [faq]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) as well as [on the Official Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).